# Como fazer cobertura utilizando Mock e C#?

Tags: c#, testes

Preciso fazer cobertura para o exemplo de método abaixo:

```
public int GetQtdCart()
{
    int qtCart = 0;
    using (var db = new SfrEntities())
    {
        qtCarteira = db.Set<Contract>().Select(x => x.Cart).Distinct().Count();
    }
    return qtCart;
}
```

Criei uma camada de teste e apliquei as referencias `NUnit` e `Pex.Microsoft.Framework`.

**Criei o teste abaixo que é bem sucedido porém a cobertura é zero:**

```
    public void TestarGetQtdCart()
    {
        Mock<IContratoRepository> mock = new Mock<IContratoRepository>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetQtdCart()).Returns(contrato.Carteira);
        var resultadoEsperado = mock.Object.GetQtdCart();
        var resultado = 0;

        Assert.AreEqual(resultado, resultadoEsperado);
    }
```

Comment: este é o site do SO em português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: A cobertura é zero porque isso não testa o método GetQtdCart().

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Segue abaixo o teste que utilizei:

```
    public void TestarGetQtdCarteira()
    {
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Contrato>>();
        mockSet.As<IList<Contrato>>().Setup(m => m.Count).Returns(contrato.Carteira);

        var mockContext = new Mock<PrgEntities>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Contrato).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new ContratoRepository(mockContext.Object);
        var contratos = service.GetQtdCarteira();

        Assert.AreEqual(contrato.Carteira, contratos);
    }
```